# How to create two HTML buttons side by side

Tags: html, css

This is a snippet of code for two buttons. I want them to be side by side but currently, one button is on top of other. as you can see

[image: Buttons on top of each other]
[image: I want it to look like this]

HTML

```
    <div class="buttons">

            <div class="action_btn">

            <button name="submit" class="action_btn submit" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="myFunction()">Save</button>
            <button name="submit" class="action_btn cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="myFunction2()">Cancel</button>

            <p id="saved"></p>

            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS

```
    .buttons {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;}

    .action_btn {
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;}
```

Comment: obviously if they both have `width: 960px;` they cannot be side-by-side on any *normal* screen resolution

Comment: it's good to play with your CSS ... you have a huge width defined, so try to reduce it. By the way if you use the same class for container and child it's impossible because   `action_btn * 2 > action_btn` whataver the width is

Answer (score 9):

```css
  .buttons {
width: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline;}

    .action_btn {
width: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline;}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">

            <div class="action_btn">

            <button name="submit" class="action_btn submit" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="myFunction()">Save</button>
            <button name="submit" class="action_btn cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="myFunction2()">Cancel</button>

            <p id="saved"></p>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`.btn{display: inline-block; margin-right: 20px;}`

> use this in css using the class or id of your button.
>
> this means that you want the buttons to be side by side

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that class action_btn is used for div and button and it interferes.
Also in your code, div that has action_btn class look like extra and needs to be deleted.
Considering the above, your code will be converted as follows.

```css
.buttons {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.action_btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button name="submit" class="action_btn submit" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="myFunction()">Save</button>
  <button name="submit" class="action_btn cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="myFunction2()">Cancel</button>
  <p id="saved"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
.buttons {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.action_btn {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

To this:

```
.buttons {
  width: auto;
}

.action_btn {
  width: auto;
}
```

Or simply delete those CSS rules altogether.

I have no idea why did you give such large numbers for the buttons' widths but the effect is that both buttons are too wide to fit side-by-side

Comment: instead of *change* I would say simply *delete*

Comment: I currently had the two buttons in the centre of the page and if I do auto it pushed the two buttons to the left side of the page.

Comment: @TashiTamu - I don't understand, you want the buttons to be in the center and also next to each-other? just wrap them in a `div` and give it `text-align:center`

Answer (score 1):

Use float

```
<div>
  <div>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="myFunction()" class="button">Save</button>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="myFunction2()" class="button">Cancel</button>
    <p id="saved"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And

```
.button{
    float:left;
    margin:2px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.form-control {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: auto;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #357ebd;
}

/* additions */
.btn-inline {
  height: 34px;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.form-control { 
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
padding-left: 10px;
}

.form-control:focus { 
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-inline">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-inline">Update</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-inline">Update</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You want the buttons themselves to have inline-block in the css.
Like this

```
    button.action_btn{display: inline-block;}
```

Once you have that, add some padding and/or margins to separate them.

Comment: a button is inline-block by default