# How do I put these two cssmade buttons side to side?

Tags: html, css, button

The code is: https://codepen.io/morganwasbanned/pen/abBNxBQ
the button is mainly made with css, so idk how to fix it. :// sorry

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,#F17C58, #E94584, #24AADB , #27DBB1,#FFDC18, #FF3706);
  background-size: 600% 100%;
  animation: gradient 16s linear ;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes gradient {
  0% {background-position: 0%}
  100% {background-position: 100%}
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,600,600italic,700italic);

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}

body {
  background:#2c3e50;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  resize: both;
}

main div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: -70px 0 0 -120px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}

a {
   text-decoration:none;
   color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="welcome.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
    <main class="wrapper">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <form method="get" action="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <button class="button-three" id="button1">Home</button>
        </form>
        <form method="get" action="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <button class="button-three" id="button2">Download</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: One way is using `.btn-group form { display: inline-block; }` or even better, use the flexbox with `.btn-group { display: flex; }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create two HTML buttons side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544089/how-to-create-two-html-buttons-side-by-side)

Answer (score 2):

I put the buttons into a horizontal list and added `display:inline;` to the style of the form.

```
 <ul>
  <li>
    <form style="display:inline;" method="get" action="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
      <button class="button-three" id="button1">Home</button>
    </form>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form style="display:inline;" method="get" action="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
      <button class="button-three" id="button2">Download</button>
    </form>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is typically used to lay things out in a nice row. Try adding `.btn-group { display: flex; flex-direction: row;}` to your css file. This should make the buttons the same height, side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly the reason why the button are not next to each other it is because you are using `form` tag instead of `a` tag. So the default display is not the same:

- `form`: `display: block`
- `a`: `display: inline`

So by changing the default display of the form, your button should be next to each other.

But there is a second problem. It is very bad to use `position: absolute` to center element. You must do that if really you have no other option because it is not responsive is this case.

So I propose you a way using flex as below:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,#F17C58, #E94584, #24AADB , #27DBB1,#FFDC18, #FF3706);
  background-size: 600% 100%;
  animation: gradient 16s linear ;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes gradient {
  0% {background-position: 0%}
  100% {background-position: 100%}
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,600,600italic,700italic);

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}

body {
  background:#2c3e50;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

main {
  position: relative;   /* USELESS Because .wrapper is getting the priority */
  height: 200px;   /* USELESS Because .wrapper is getting the priority */
  width: 60%;   /* USELESS Because .wrapper is getting the priority */
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  resize: both;
  display:flex;   /** ADDED **/
}

main div {
  /*width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: -70px 0 0 -120px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 20px;*/
  display: flex;              /** ADDED **/
  height:100px;               /** ADDED **/
  justify-content: center;    /** ADDED **/
  margin: auto;               /** ADDED **/
}

main form{
  margin: auto 0;   /** ADDED **/
}

a {
   text-decoration:none;
   color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="welcome.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
    <main class="wrapper">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <form method="get" action="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <button class="button-three" id="button1">Home</button>
        </form>
        <form method="get" action="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <button class="button-three" id="button2">Download</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```