# How to align two button in single row?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is my code :

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix modal-footer">
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-info">Yes</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-info">No</button>
</div>
</div>
```

What I need is my button to be display in single row with a small space in between.

But I got like this:

[image]

How to fix this?. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create two HTML buttons side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544089/how-to-create-two-html-buttons-side-by-side)

Comment: The code in you question actually make the two buttons in single row even with the bootstrap classes so there might be something else that is affecting the layout. Do you have any other css rules set?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easiest possible modern solution:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
   <button>Button 1</button>
   <button>Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the css of your .ui-dialog-buttonset class:

```
.ui-dialog-buttonset button {
    display: inline-block;
}
.ui-dialog-buttonset > button:last-child {
    margin-left: 16px;
}
```

Comment: missing the gap, mate ;-)

Answer (score 0):

display: flex;
or
display: inline-block;